# AutoMapper nulling out Entity Key

Tags: entity-framework, automapper

I have a simple update method:

```
public void Update(Users user)
    {
        tblUserData userData = _context.tblUserDatas.Where(u => u.IDUSER == user.IDUSER).FirstOrDefault();
        if (userData != null)
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<Users, tblUserData>();
            userData = Mapper.Map<Users, tblUserData>(user);
            _context.SaveChanges()
        }
    }
```

When I call Map(), my entity key in userData is nulled out, which was causing me no end of confusion. Anyone know how I can map properties over while retaining my entity key?

Thanks!

Chris

Comment: Does your destination object had the exact same property names as the source?

Comment: It does, but if the destination object has a property that the source object doesn't, would Automapper wipe that property out?

Comment: Wont wipe it out but it wont map the value either, so it would map null or some other default.